# How to find the probability, mean and cdf using a pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f_{x}(x)= \large \frac{1}{5} e^{\frac{-x}{5}}$, $x>0$
>
> a. Sketch the graph of $f_x$. Use the pdf to find $P(X>5)$. Find the mean of $X$.
>
> b. Find the cdf of $X$. Use it to compute $P(X>7)$. Also use the cdf to compute the median of the distribution. Compare it to the mean of the distribution to the median in terms of the skewness of the distribution.
>
> c. Finally, compute the interquartile range which is the difference between the $75^{th}$ percentile and the $25^{th}$ percentile.

Comment: Do you recognize the distribution? Hint: $e$.

Comment: This is exponential distribution see this[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

Comment: You can integrate the PDF to get the CDF.

Comment: **Eight** orders given, eight reasons not to answer.

Answer (score 6):

a) Some calculus needed. For the probability that $X\gt 5$, you need to find $\int_5^\infty \frac{1}{5}e^{-x/5}\,dx$.

For the mean, probably you are expected to use the fact that if $f_X(x)$ is the density function, then the mean is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx$. In our case that comes down to evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{5}e^{-x/5}\,dx$. The antiderivative you need is usually calculated by integration by parts.

b) he cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ of $X$ is $0$ if $x\lt 0$.  For $x\ge 0$, it is given by 
$$F_X(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{5}e^{-t/5}\,dt.$$

Now that we have $F_X$, note that $\Pr(X\gt 7)=1-\Pr(X\le 7)=1-F_X(7)$.

To go on, unfortunately I must reveal that for $x\ge 0$, it turns out that $F_X(x)=1-e^{-x/5}$.

To find the median $m$, we need to solve the equation
$$1-e^{-m/5}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
In solving this, you will need to use the (natural) logarithm function.

c) The $25$-th percentile is the point $a$ such that $\Pr(X\le a)=0.25$.  To find $a$ you proceed much like in the calculation of the median.

The $75$-th percentile $b$ is computed in a similar way. Finally, calculate $b-a$.

Comment: This helped significantly.
Just curious... what is the P($X<7$)?

Comment: $\Pr(X\lt 7)=1-e^{-7/5}$. Note, because this is a continuous distribution, that $\Pr(X=7)=0$.